# How can I show one element from one of two tables in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A has the id for a Company of which the name can be either in table B or table C. 
What I'm trying to achieve is to show the fetched name in a new column, something like:

```
SELECT Bank.Name OR Company.Name AS 'CompanyName'
FROM Account 
INNER JOIN Company
ON Account.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID OR
Account.CounterpartyID = Company.CompanyID
INNER JOIN Bank
ON Account.CompanyID = Bank.BankID OR
Account.CounterpartyID = Bank.BankID 
WHERE ...
```

Can this work like this or do I need to use multiple SELECTs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `CASE` like `Select CASE WHEN B.Name != '' THEN  B.Name WHEN C.Name != '' THEN  C.Name END as  CompanyName`

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help; otherwise we have the guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `LEFT JOIN`.  You seem to want names for both the company and the counterparty.  That would be two columns and additional joins:

```
SELECT COALESCE(c.Name, b.Name) AS CompanyName,
       COALESCE(cc.Name, bc.Name) AS CounterpartyName,
FROM Account a LEFT JOIN
     Company c
     ON a.CompanyID = c.CompanyID LEFT JOIN
     Bank b
     ON a.CompanyID = b.BankID AND
        c.CompanyID IS NULL LEFT JOIN
     Company cc
     ON a.CounterpartyID = cc.CompanyID LEFT JOIN
     Bank bc
     ON a.CounterpartyID = bc.BankID AND
        cc.CompanyID IS NULL
WHERE ...
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!
Can you explain to me why I need the null check? Or is this just a precaution?

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- There will be ONE, or NO rows in TableA or TableB for the company
- If there is a row in both TableA and TableB then taking the company name from TableA is acceptable

With those assumptions this code should do the trick:

```
SELECT  A.CompanyId,
        COALESCE(B.CompanyName, C.CompanyName)
FROM    TableA A
LEFT
JOIN    TableB B
        ON A.CompanyId = B.CompanyId
LEFT
JOIN    TableC C
        ON A.CompanyId = C.CompanyId
WHERE   TableA.CompanyId = 1234
```

Essentially what this code is doing is joining the tables together, using a `LEFT JOIN` so that rows from `TableA` don't get excluded by the absence of a row in either of `TableB` or `TableC`, then using `COALESCE` to get the first non-NULL value from either of the two tables for the `CompanyName` column.

The result of the query (if you were using `SELECT *`) where `TableA` doesn't contain a row would look a little like this:

[image: A visual representation of the result set the query would operate against]

Just to give an example of the data the query would be working against.

Comment: I think I messed up the explanation a bit.

There is an ID in Table A for every row, for this ID a name can be found in table B or table C.
No matter where it is found, it should be shown in the same column.

Comment: @deadcrumb that's what the query I wrote should give you, via the `COALESCE` - the screenshot is if you replaced the current `SELECT` with `SELECT *` to act as an illustration of what the result of the JOINs would look like =)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT b.name FROM tableB b WHERE b.name IS NOT NULL
    ) THEN b.name AS 'CompanyName'

    WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT c.name FROM tableC c WHERE c.name IS NOT NULL
    ) THEN c.name AS 'CompanyName'
END
FROM tableA a
...
```

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done with `COALESCE()` function if you have `NULL`s, or even `IIF()` function or `CASE` expression

Instead of `SELECT Bank.Name OR Company.Name AS 'CompanyName'` you can do

```
SELECT COALESCE(Bank.Name, Company.Name) AS CompanyName
```

OR

```
SELECT IIF(Bank.Name IS NULL, Company.Name, Bank.Name) AS CompanyName
```

OR

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Bank.Name IS NULL
            THEN Company.Name
            ELSE Bank.Name
       END  AS CompanyName
```

If you mean `''` then

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Bank.Name = ''
            THEN Company.Name
            ELSE Bank.Name
       END  AS CompanyName
```